# Oracle - Copy data from one row to another based on dynamic selected columns

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a table with two rows and I need to copy some data in row A to row B.
My biggest concern here is that the columns involved are not static in name or number (table can grow or shrink in column number).

I came up with a solution that i don't like at all...

```sql
create or replace
PROCEDURE Z_COPY_TASK_ATT_PE
(
  par_oldRowId IN VARCHAR2,
  par_newRowId IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  var_update VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
  var_crr_col_value_old VARCHAR2(10 BYTE);
  var_crr_select VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
BEGIN

  var_update := 'UPDATE PLANNING_ENTITY SET ';

  for i in (
            Select COLUMN_NAME 
            from user_tab_columns 
            where table_name='PLANNING_ENTITY' 
            and lower(COLUMN_NAME) like 'code%'
            )
  loop

    var_crr_select := 'select ' || i.column_name 
      || ' from planning_entity where planning_code = ''' 
      || par_oldRowId || ''''; 

    execute immediate var_crr_select
      into var_crr_col_value_old;

    var_update := var_update || i.column_name || ' = ''' || var_crr_col_value_old || ''', ';
  end loop;

  var_update := SUBSTR(var_update, 0, length(var_update)-2 );
  var_update := var_update || ' where planning_code = ''' || par_newRowId || '''';

  execute immediate var_update;
  commit;
END;
```

My major issue here (for me at least) is the fact that i need to make the select for each iteration of the loop. It would be really nice if i could make a select that returned something like column|name and then all I needed to do was i.column and i.value.

What do you think?

===== Solution following Marmite Bomber Answer =====

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Z_COPY_TASK_ATT_PE
(
  par_oldRowId IN VARCHAR2,
  par_newRowId IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  var_update VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE);
  var_columns varchar2(4000 BYTE);
BEGIN

  Select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN group (order by column_name) into var_columns
  from user_tab_columns 
  where table_name='PLANNING_ENTITY' 
  and lower(COLUMN_NAME) like 'code%';

  var_update := 'UPDATE PLANNING_ENTITY PE1 SET (' || var_columns ||
    ') = (SELECT ' || var_columns || ' FROM PLANNING_ENTITY PE2 WHERE PE2.PLANNING_CODE = ''' || par_oldRowId ||
    ''') WHERE PE1.PLANNING_CODE = ''' || par_newRowId || '''';

  execute immediate var_update;
  commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this update

```
 UPDATE t1 a
 SET (code1, code2) = (
   SELECT code1,code2
   FROM t1 b
   WHERE b.planning_code = 'new')
 where a.planning_code = 'old';
```

you need only generate comma separated list of the column names that should be updated and apply it twice in the statement. In the example *code1,code2*.

Comment: Hi @Marmite Bomber, I can't believe i missed this one... this would definitely work better :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
begin
  for i in (select * from PLANNING_ENTITY where planning_code = newrow) loop   
    update PLANNING_ENTITY set row = i where planning_code = oldrow;   
  end loop;
end;
```

For downvoters:

```
SQL> select version from v$instance;

VERSION
-----------------
11.2.0.4.0

SQL> create table it_works_in_oracle (n1 number, n2 number, n3 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into it_works_in_oracle values(1, 1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into it_works_in_oracle values(2, 2, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into it_works_in_oracle values(3, 3, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from it_works_in_oracle;

        N1         N2         N3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          2
         3          3          3

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  oldrow number:=1;
  newrow number:=3;
begin
  for i in (select * from it_works_in_oracle where n1 = newrow) loop
    update it_works_in_oracle set row = i where n1 = oldrow;
  end loop;
end;  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from it_works_in_oracle;

        N1         N2         N3
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          3          3
         2          2          2
         3          3          3
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET ROW = ...` updates **every** column, however TO wants to update only columns where name is like `CODE%`. Even worse it will also update column `PLANNING_CODE`, i.e. it doubles row of "newRowId".

Comment: OK, You are right, I understood the question wrong. But TO still doesn't have to run query for EVERY column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similar to this (not tested):

```
var_update := 'UPDATE PLANNING_ENTITY a SET (';

  FOR i IN (
            SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
            WHERE table_name='PLANNING_ENTITY' 
            AND LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE 'code%'
            )
  LOOP
        var_update := var_update || i.column_name ||',';
  END LOOP;
  var_update := REGEXP_REPLACE(var_update, ',$', ')');
  var_update := var_update ||' = (SELECT ';
  FOR i IN (
            SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
            WHERE table_name='PLANNING_ENTITY' 
            AND LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE 'code%'
            )
  LOOP
        var_update := var_update || i.column_name ||',';
  END LOOP;
  var_update := REGEXP_REPLACE(var_update, ',$');
  var_update := var_update || ' FROM PLANNING_ENTITY b WHERE planning_code = :newRowId) ';
  var_update := var_update || ' WHERE a.planning_code = :oldRowId';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_update USING par_newRowId, par_oldRowId;
```

Comment: Hi @Wernfried. I had to go with Marmite Bomber answer because of simplicity (it avoids loops and all) and most probably performance too.

Comment: My solution it the same as from Marmite Bomber. Only difference is the UPDATE statement is generated dynamically instead of a static one. But yes, by using `LISTAGG` you avoid one loop.